# Looking synonymous for a person that require a minimal supervision

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrases, meaning-in-context, determiners

Is there any word for a person that can do things with a minimal supervision? Or what is the synonymous for a person that require a minimal supervision

Comment: Sometimes called a "self-starter"

Comment: On both resumes and job descriptions, I’ve seen   “An **independent** individual who is **self-motivating** and **needs little supervision**” used to describe such a person.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I strongly encourage you to review the [guidance for making single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), as well as the site [tour] and [help] to see if this question can be strengthened.

Comment: "Free-range chicken" would work, except for the "chicken" part.

Answer (score 3):

Independent.

In this case, it is a trait that suggests someone who does not need to always be told what to do and can make their own decisions.

Comment: Yes, if one is independent, they can handle themselves in any situation which implies minimal, if not any, supervision.

Answer (score 1):

A person who doesn't need a group to function efficiently is or can be *independent*.

A person who doesn't need a boss to look over his shoulder is *self-motivated*.

A person who doesn't need a boss to give instructions for each task is a *self-starter*.

A person who can be or has been trained quickly and thereafter is able to function without supervision is a *quick learner*.

You could always just go with a phrase: *she does just fine on her own*, *doesn't need much supervision*, or *usually works best unsupervised*. (The last might hint at difficulties with authority, though.)